# Как избавиться от большого количества циклов в примере (ES5)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть следующий код

```js
function delDelivery() {
  var groups = "123, 444",
    deliverys = "4424, 5255",
    clientGroup = 123;

  var init = function() {
    var arr = idToNumb(groups);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (clientGroup === arr[i]) {
        getRadioNumbers();
        break
      }
    }
  };

  var idToNumb = function(arr) {
    var splitArr = arr.split(','),
      numbArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {
      numbArr.push(+splitArr[i]);
    }

    return numbArr
  };

  var getRadioNumbers = function() {
    $('.co-delivery_method').each(function() {
      var val = +$(this).find('input[data-delivery-id]').data('delivery-id');
      viewHandler(val);
    });
  };

  var viewHandler = function(numb) {
    var arr = idToNumb(deliverys);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (numb === arr[i]) {
        $('[data-delivery-id="' + numb + '"]').parents('.co-delivery_method').css('background', 'red');
      }
    }
  };

  init();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="co-delivery_method"> <input type="radio" data-delivery-id="4424" /> </div>
<div class="co-delivery_method"> <input type="radio" data-delivery-id="42134" /> </div>
```

Пример принимает строки (а начале примера), если 3я переменная равна одному из значений 1й, обрабатывает 2ю переменную и ищет соответсвия с дата-атрибутом в html, меняет фон если находит

Он имеет достаточно большое количество циклов, как мне кажется, как можно правильнее и лучше написать такое? (jquery, ES5)

Comment: для начала надо хотя бы сказать, что он (данный код) должен делать

Comment: добавил, спасибо

Comment: Кажется можно убрать функцию `idToNumb` и вместо неё писать `arr.split(',').map(parseInt)`

Comment: А ещё можно вместо цикла в `init` написать `if (arr.indexOf(clientGroup) !== -1) getRadioNumbers();`

Comment: @diraria, _вместо неё писать `arr.split(',').map(parseInt)`_ - попробуй что это вернет :-)

Comment: @NikolayMuravets, все равно непонятно, что делает приведенный код. В текущем виде он вообще работает как ожидается?

Comment: @Grundy попробую позже, а что там не так-то будет?)

Comment: @diraria, результат будет весьма неожиданным ;-)

Comment: @Grundy ну скажи что там будет, я просто не могу сейчас попробовать, а мне интересно

Comment: @Grundy Да, работает, код просто обрабатывает 2 строки, это часть кода, в котором я увидел проблему, во 2й и 1й функции заменил циклы на indexOf, код стал поменьше и красивее) .map - не подходит, к сожалению (нету в ES5)

Comment: @NikolayMuravets, ты не прав, как раз в ES5 - map уже есть

Comment: да, вижу в ES5.1 добавлено, я что-то уверен был что с 6го, спасибо за поправку

Comment: @NikolayMuravets возможно тебе будет интересно знать, что es6+ можно переводить в es5 с помощью [babel](https://babeljs.io/)